# How can i hide image in jquery and make the label stay at same place?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am  building a game. My character has 5 lives. When my character gets killed I want to hide 1 life of 5. When I do that with jQuery the label of "Lives:" moves a little bit right (to fill the space formerly occupied by tne life I just hid.

Example:

[image]

```html
  <div class="items">
    <p class="welcomemsg" id="or">welcome</p>
    <p  style="font-family:Bubble; color:white; font-size:28px; margin-right: 5%;" >Lives:
    <img class="lives" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live1">
    <img class="lives" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live2">
    <img class="lives" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live3">
    <img class="lives" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live4">
  </p>
</div>
```

```js
  if (board[shape.i][shape.j] == 14) {
    if(livesCounter!=0) {
        $("#live"+livesCounter).hide();
        livesCounter--;
    }
  }
```

```css
    .items{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        }

    .welcomemsg{
        font-family: 'Bubble';
        font-size: 32px;
        color:white;
        margin-left:5%;
    }
```

How can I make my label stay in place?

Comment: Maybe try: `$("#live"+livesCounter).css('visibility', 'hidden');`  In this context: `The element is hidden (but still takes up space)`

Comment: @PaulT. is right on that one. Setting visibility to hidden will work. Setting opacity to 0 will also work, but it will preserve clickability, which you may not want to do. You _can_ have something unclickable with opacity 0 and visibility visible, but it's an extra step.

Comment: @PaulT. you are awsome!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.lives {
    display: inline-block;
    with: 80 px;
}
```

```html
<span class="lives">
<img class="live" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live1">
<img class="live" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live1">
<img class="live" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live1">
<img class="live" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live1">
<img class="live" src="./assets/img/logopac.png" alt="pacslogo" id="live1">
</span>
```